# can not find coordinator import screen in hue console?

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, hue

I am looking for this screen in my CDH5 console to import an oozie coordinator file.

http://demo.gethue.com/oozie/import_coordinator/

There doesn't seem to be any way to navigate this screen.

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

There is an 'import' button on the Coordinator page: http://demo.gethue.com/oozie/list_coordinators/

In Hue 3.8
A new export and / export is planned for Hue 4. It will let you export workflows in both XML / JSON Hue format and import from Hue’s format.

Comment: I was on that page. Only the create button showed up. No import and no trash buttons.